# Inside my own Angular service, how do you get the return value back to the Controller that called the service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, service, promise

I'm having trouble figuring out the success and error callbacks inside $http in angular and the "then" part of a promise.  The $http service returns a promise.  Is the "success" callback an example of a "then"?
What if I stick $http inside my own service?  How would I do this?

I think code is easier to show my questions:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $log, BooksService) {
    BooksService.retrieveAllBooks().then(function(results) {
      $scope.allBooks = results;
    });
  });


app.factory('BooksService', function($http,$log) {
  var service = {
    retrieveAllBooks: function() {
      return $http({
        method: 'GET','https://hugebookstore.org/allbooks'
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json"
        }
      }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
         var allbooks = transformDataIntoBooksArray(data);//this function exists and just takes raw data and turns them into Book objects
         return allbooks;/*how is this "success" callback related to the "then"() callback in app.controller above?*/
      };
      }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $log.error('here is an error'+data + status + headers + config);
      });
    }
  };
  return service;
});
```

**Questions about the `app.controller` code:**

do I need to use a `"then()"` function inside `app.controller?`

I just want my controller to fetch me a list of all the books using the `BooksService`.  The `BooksService` already has a "`then`" type of clause, which is the "`success`" callback.  It seems like I have an unnecssary "`then`".  Is that true?

Also, when is the "`then`" called, and can I put anything in the `then's` callback function's parameters?

I don't understand what parameters are supplied by default and what I can add.

**Questions about the `app.factory` code:**

First, this is what I understand the code to be doing.

I'm creating a `BooksService` using the factory() methods and not the service() methods available in Angular.
I'm defining a function called `retrieveAllBooks()` that under the hood, is making an asynchronous GET request using $http in Angular, which itself is a service.  `RetrieveAllBooks()` is a nothing more than a wrapper around the $http GET service, which makes it easy for clients to simply call `BooksService.retrieveAllBooks()` and be handed an array of Book objects.

When is the "`success`" callback executed and what is its relation to the "`then`" callback in my `app.controller?`

It doesn't appear that a `return` value inside my `success`() callback is ever returned back to `app.controller`.  Why?

How can I get the allbooks array returned back to the app.controller which is what originally called `BooksService.retrieveAllBooks()`?

Are there any other parameters allowed in the `success` callback?

What do I need to return from the `retrieveAllBooks`() function definition?  Do I return the `$http promise` alone, or do I need to `return` something from both the success and `error` callbacks as well?

I know this is longwinded but I hope that someone can help me, b/c this to pattern--separating out my network calls into its own `service` layer as opposed to calling $`http` directly inside my `controller` layer, will be done over and over again.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `success` and `error` handlers are specific to the promise returned by `$http`. However, they're similar to `.then(function onFulfill(){}, function onReject(){})`.

It's up to you if you want to return that promise directly or implement something else.

Generally, your controller shouldn't be concerned about how your service handled the request. Thus, in my opinion, you shouldn't return that promise directly. Just handle the success and error case in your service. Return the result if the request succeeds and throw an Error if the request fails.

You can then use the generic `.then(function onFulfill(){}, function onReject(){})` pattern in your controller, as this is always valid and expected with promises in Angular.

The `onFulfill` callback always receives your result as a parameter, the `onReject` callback receives the Error as a parameter.

So, what options do you have? Either drop your `.success` and `.error` callbacks in your service altogether and handle the transformation in the success case in your controller, or create a new deferred promise to return the transformed results:

```
app.factory('BooksService', function($http,$log,$q) {
  var service = {
    retrieveAllBooks: function() {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      $http({
        method: 'GET','https://hugebookstore.org/allbooks'
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json"
        }
      }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
         var allbooks = transformDataIntoBooksArray(data);//this function exists and just takes raw data and turns them into Book objects
         deferred.resolve( allbooks );
      };
      }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $log.error('here is an error'+data + status + headers + config);
        deferred.reject( new Error( 'here is an error'+data + status + headers + config );
      });
      return deferred.promise;
    }
  };
  return service;
});
```

Although, we can save that if we consider:
 - Errors are tracked by Angular already
 - The deferred is excess, and can be avoided
 - Content-Type and Accept are generated by Angular and the serer anyway.
 - We can save the anonymous wrapper for our action

So, we end up with:

```
app.factory('BooksService', function($http) {
  return {
    retrieveAllBooks: function() { 
      return $http.get('https://hugebookstore.org/allbooks').
             then(transformDataIntoBooksArray); // Error tracked by Angular already
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey Oliver, thank you VERY much.  I definitely agree that the controller should not have to do any transformations and should be handed the array of Books.  It looks like I'll be taking your implementation, and I will need to read up on the $q and the defer() method.  I for some reason had thought that the $q was no longer needed in recent versions of angular (yikes!) or for sure was an advanced usage and would not be needed for my "usual use case" and so had glossed over it.

Comment: "Success and error handlers are ... just syntactic sugar over implementing .then(...)". Sorry, this is not true.`.success()` and `.error()` are each guaranteed to return their original input promise, while `.then()` is guaranteed to return a new promise, the value/reason of which is determined by whichever of its handlers (if any) is executed. `.then()` thus has "filtering" power that is not possessed by `.success()` or `.error()` individually. The Angular documentation is not good at bringing out this point.

Comment: Adding to what @Roamer-1888 said, the deferred you are returning is unneeded. $http returns a promise. If you use `.then` you can simply return the resulting promise and use return values.