# returning value to higher scope inside from a chained functions in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function getUsers that I want to return JSON from an web api  .. but I cant seem to get the data out, I can't return the data because the function is inside $http. What should i do ?

```
function getUsers() {
            $http({ method: 'GET', url: '/api/loginapi/userdetails' })
                     .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                         details = data;
                     });
            return details;
           }
```

Comment: The callback needs to call another function and pass the data as a parameter, or assign it to some "outer" variable that is accessible to the callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http) makes an asynchronous call, so you can't immediately return fetched data.

What you can return is a [promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24q). Good news, `$http()` returns one:

```
function getUsers() {
    return $http({ method: 'GET', url: '/api/loginapi/userdetails' });
}
```

Then you can use your function:

```
getUsers().then(function(data) {
    var details = data;

    // Process your details!
});
```

Comment: THANX !! I was trying to figure out what promise is .. and how to use it during async calls .. your comment made it so simple and easy to understand !! love you !! I wish I had enough reputation to give you a vote up !! :D :D

Comment: You're welcome, I'm pleased to have been helpful to you!

Answer (score 1):

You can access data there for sure, nothing is 'inside' `$http`, I suggest you pass in a callback to `getUsers()` and do whatever you want with the returned data:

```
var getUsers=function(callback){
            $http({ method: 'GET', url: '/api/loginapi/userdetails' })
                     .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                         callback(data);
                     });
}
```

and use it like this inside your controller:

```
getUsers(function(users){
    $scope.whatever = users;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I created plunkr for your question http://plnkr.co/edit/lqX4apmvnKM3i5jGZDQM?p=preview

$http return a promise. Please read details about promise at http://johnmunsch.com/2013/07/17/angularjs-services-and-promises/ . It is an important understanding if you want to write asynchronous application. This is another useful link - [Inside my own Angular service, how do you get the return value back to the Controller that called the service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23329485/inside-my-own-angular-service-how-do-you-get-the-return-value-back-to-the-contr?rq=1) . Refer to answer. It explains how to use promise and deffered in angularjs.

```
    var app = angular.module('plunker', []);


    app.service('UserService', ['$http', '$q',
        function($http, $q) {
            this.getUser = function() {
                return $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: 'data.json'
                });
            };
        }
    ]);
    app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, UserService) {
        $scope.user = {};
        UserService.getUser().then(function(response){
            $scope.user = response.data;
        });
    });
```